# How do I enter commands in single-user mode?

Tags: macos, single-user

After every command line do I have to press enter and wait for it to end before I go to the next one? I have no clue at all and am desperate to solve this problem. This is my first time using single-user mode.

```
/sbin/fsck -fy /
/sbin/mount -uw /
mkdir /Disabled_System_Library_Extensions
cd /Disabled_System_Library_Extensions
mv /System/Library/Extensions/ATI* .
mv /System/Library/Extensions/AMD* .
touch /System/Library/Extensions
exit
```

Comment: And yes you have to wait for each command to finish

Answer (score 1):

After you've typed a line, press the enter key. Wait until the command has finished before typing the next line and repeating. If you've ever used Terminal, it is the identical process.